# PCRE pcre_exec thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pcre

I have a C program that uses a PCRE regex to determine if a process in a cgroup should be added to one variable or another. I spawn a thread to read the cpuacct.stat file in each running cgroup, where the number of threads never exceeded the number of cores. These samples and results are then combined into one of two variables.

The relevant snippet of code is:

```
    pcreExecRet = pcre_exec(reCompiled,
                        pcreExtra,
                        queue,
                        strlen(queue),          // length of string
                        0,                      // Start looking at this point
                        0,                      // OPTIONS
                        subStrVec,
                        30);                    // Length of subStrVec

    //CRITICAL SECTION?
    pthread_mutex_lock(&t_lock); //lock mutex
    while (sumFlag == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&ok_add, &t_lock); //wait on ok signal
    }

    if(pcreExecRet > 0) {
        sumOne += loadavg;
    } else if (pcreExecRet == PCRE_ERROR_NOMATCH){
        sumTwo += loadavg;
    } else {
        perror("Could not determine sum!\n"); //if this fails

    }

    sumFlag = 1;

    pthread_cond_signal(&ok_add); //signal that it is ok to add
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&t_lock); //unlock mutex
```

My question is whether or not the pcre_exec() call is thread-safe? Should it be moved into the critical section? I know the compiled regex is thread safe, but I'm not sure about pcreExtra (const pcre_extra) or subStrVec (int *ovector). These variables are global for now.

Comment: What does the documentation for `pcre_exec()` say? And also, you can use [*helgrind*](http://www.valgrind.org/info/tools.html#helgrind) to check for thread related problems.

Comment: Ovector is not sharable between threads for reasons I would have thought are obvious. I would allocate one for each thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is thread safe, all *PCRE* functions are but you should be careful under certain conditions

The following is from the [manual pages for *PCRE*](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)

> ```
> MULTITHREADING
>
>    The PCRE functions can be used in  multi-threading  applications,  with
>    the  proviso  that  the  memory  management  functions  pointed  to  by
>    pcre_malloc, pcre_free, pcre_stack_malloc, and pcre_stack_free, and the
>    callout  and  stack-checking  functions  pointed to by pcre_callout and
>    pcre_stack_guard, are shared by all threads.
>
>    The compiled form of a regular expression is not altered during  match-
>    ing, so the same compiled pattern can safely be used by several threads
>    at once.
>
>    If the just-in-time optimization feature is being used, it needs  sepa-
>    rate  memory stack areas for each thread. See the pcrejit documentation
>    for more details.
> ```

Comment: Right, I read this, and the compiled regex is thread safe, but I wasn't sure if the pcre_extra or the ovector arguments could be shared. I'll give helgrind a try as well. Thanks!

Comment: @anthozep It's safe for pcre_extra (it's really part of the regex definition), but ovector is absolutely not safe to share, as it contains the actual match *result*.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Right, and all of the global variables are of course unsafe without syncronization.